# Ignoring a Commit during delivery from one Repository to another

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

We have two different repository for development and Release activities. For example group of developers will commit their code changes in development repository and these commits will be delivered to Release repository.
We are using Stash-GIT to commit our activities. My question is, Do we have any specific command to ignore a particular commit during delivery process from Development stream to Release repository meanwhile all the other commits should be delivered successfully.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot tell git to push/pull a branch and leave out a certain commit. Git by design always works with complete paths through history and you can never "skip" a commit.

That said, depending on what you actually want to do and how your process actually works (you're telling us precious little about that), there might be ways to work with branches, tags etc. to reach your overarching goal. Feel free to expand your question.